# How come it is showing Diamond to my account in moderator private message?

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-messages

I just got a Moderator Private Message from Super User's Moderator Team.

https://superuser.com/users/message/629?noredirect=1#629 (For Super User moderators only)

Because I failed last few reviews I got this message from moderator. OK I will improve my review task from now onwards.

Now as rules regulations when a user get message from moderator he/she may get a chance to reply back to those moderators.

I too got the same reply page, but to my surprise it is showing ♦ besides my profile name, see the image below:

> [image]

I know that, the page is designed to reply a private message to those moderator team who reviewed my "review summary".

But my question is why it is showing a ♦ with my Profile name in that page

Comment: You've been drafted to be a mod. The changes are still processing through the system, obviously.

Comment: @Michael As far as I know, unless there's some _weird_ shenanigans going down on SU, people aren't just flat out drafted for mod positions without their knowledge and consent.

Comment: I was joking, @Knights. Not very well, obviously.

Comment: @Michael Potentially confusing... writing for the OP, not future readers

Comment: You lucky person

Comment: @hims056, I think link is visible to all mods, not only super user mods.

Comment: @Lucifer - No. Moderators on other sites are normal users.

Comment: @hims056, yes agree with you, but my "mod" I meant site mod + [community managers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/173001) and  developers too.

Comment: @Lucifer - employee & devs can see everithing (AFAIK). So no need to include them ;) However you may edit your question.

Comment: @hims056, It's ok. I am not blaming you. I was just saying my point of view. :)

Comment: I would like to see ♦ next to my name too. :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya, here you go: Anoop Vaidya ♦

Comment: Many many thanks Ben. I am top of the world now. :)

Comment: When the private message system was built probably only moderators could use it, without exception. So the diamond was hard coded into the view. After adding exception that allows mortal users to reply they simply forgot about the hard coded diamond. And of course, it's.... [Jeff fault](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/)!

Comment: To reproduce I am going to... :)

Comment: Not reproducing, is it still there for you?

Comment: @TimPost, I replied to moderators with "Sorry Message" and then I didnt get any reply back from them, so i can't see that page again.

Comment: Also, why are certain names on that image light blue? Yours and Sathya's in particular are a different color than the rest.

Comment: @asad, those links (to the profiles) are visited

Comment: @Asad , light blue color shows that it is visited link.q

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We regret to inform you that your temporary single-page moderator status has been rescinded.  This bug gets fixed in the next build.

Comment: No problem, Nick :)