# How does one find the reason for one's own account suspension?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, user-accounts, account-suspension

This morning I received the following vague email:

> Hello,
>
> I'm writing in reference to your User Experience Stack Exchange account:
>
> https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/75582/wogsland
>
> I wanted to let you know that we've observed some rudeness in your latest activity. We get it; anyone who's ever tried to engage with others online has probably been tempted to lash out at someone else. This is just a friendly reminder that we require all participants to act in a professional and civil tone when using these sites. If another user has wronged you in some way, please do not respond in kind. Simply flag the content for moderator attention and move on.
>
> If this is a simple misunderstanding, no harm done. Sometimes it is helpful to remind ourselves on occasion that keeping things friendly and constructive doesn't have to be at odds with being right — so enjoy the site, bring your sense of humor, and please be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know.
>
> We have temporarily suspended your account; you may return after 7 days.
>
> Regards,
>   [Benny Skogberg](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/4679/benny-skogberg)
>   User Experience Stack Exchange moderator

---

I'm looking back through my questions & comments, but I can't figure out what was considered rude. How can I learn the specific reason for my suspension?

Comment: Your rude comments are almost certainly deleted in this case, so you won't find them in your profile.

Comment: Usually it is deleted comments, did you reply to the message asking for more details?

Comment: @BhargavRao I did. Just trying to learn if there's something I missed.

Comment: That's quite literally the standard message for such things. And well, we don't know who you could have been rude to. Have you?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I have no idea. I haven't even had a disagreement with somebody on UX yet.

Answer (score 20):

What's not clear???

> we've observed some rudeness in your latest activity

And:

> This is just a friendly reminder that we require all participants to act in a professional and civil tone when using these sites.

---

> How can I learn the specific reason for a suspension?

Reply to the moderator message and ask for details. Normal users here are not privy to such details.

Comment: What's not clear is that I don't think I was rude anywhere and I certainly wasn't intending to be. If I don't know what behavior the moderator wants me to change, then I can't very well change it now can I?

Comment: Like I said - you need to respond to the moderator message you got. There's nothing we can do here.

Comment: Come on, he wants to air his dirty laundry in public.  Stop teasing us.

Comment: @Oded To be fair, while we're all definitely traumatized and generally fed up with zillions of "omg why was I suspended" rants and such on metas, and I totally get that, this *particular* OP was refreshingly tame (relatively), and probably not deserving of three question marks after "What's not clear?". It's easy to let general burn-out from handling these types of questions affect our attitude right out of the gate.

Comment: @JasonC - I've been told there's some history there, so...

Comment: The initial email should be more detailed and not require to ask questions due to the vague “some rudeness in your latest activity”

Answer (score -20):

Mods can describe the reason, and in my opinion they should. *If they don't do it, it is evil.* Although they aren't needed to do it, in my opinion it is at least questionable behavior to miss it. Furthermore, it opens the door before misuse accusations. Their template in these cases looks like:

> "You were bad, you are not a nice guy, you posted insulting comments
>   like these:
>
> ...examples of your insulting comments...
>
> These comments were removed. Furthermore, you were so evil that I ban
>   you for a year."

Although it is formulated more politely and with perfect English, but it is the essence.

As they cage somebody, they can select a list of templates, so they don't have to bore too long with a cage.

Also I experienced lately that I got a (similarly short) caging but without citing the real posts, why I was so bad. I hope, it won't become a new custom. If the mod doesn't cite the reason, it makes himself unattackable on an unfair way.

Posts leading to a suspension are also posts should be removed by their content. Thus, you can't see them, except the rare cases if you have 10000 reputation points on the site, which makes for you visible to see removed posts (but note, only mods can see removed comments, not even the 10k+ users). This is a highly problematic thing here on the SE, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285275/259412) you can downvote my related answer arguing against this.

But don't worry on a week long suspension, it is essentially nothing. It could be even [far worse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283176/259412). Mods can only suspend anybody at most for a year; and only for their site. They tend to give the suspension times incrementally. The message you've now got will remain forever attached to your account, and it will be visible by the CMs and mods. Your next suspension will be at least 1 month.

All cage decisions are automatically reviewed by the CMs, but they mostly don't intervene. If you think it was really evil, you can contact them on the `/contact` URL of your page, but don't expect earth-shaking changes, particularly in the case of such short bans.

CMs can provide network-wide or much longer cages; an [example](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/4864/ron-maimon). In the database record describing your account there is a date field for that, the maximal value is `9999-12-31`. It is long, but the suspensions are only temporary, so we only have to wait.

If your cage happened not on a comment, but on an answer or question: you can still read your own deleted posts (you can even edit them), although the SE intentionally doesn't provide any way to find them. You have to remember its link, or to find it is its browser history. Only mods and yet higher powers can list the deleted posts of others (and listing the deleted comments is possible only with db-access, as far I know).

Comment: I would like to mention, this comment got its first downvote in 15:57:02, while it was posted in 15:56:58. It means, the most beloved downvoter had full 4 seconds to perceive my post, open it, read it, understand it, and to decide, that it is not useful. We have really *exceptional* people between us.

Comment: I was the third downvoter, and it's mainly because 1. you're not a mod. do you have a source for the "template"? (i.e. meta post saying that) 2. it seems like you're complaining about _your own_ suspension, in a passive-aggressive way. 3. Furthermore, you're not even answering the question.  You don't explain why he was, you just say "it could be worse".

Comment: It takes less than a second to reach the "If they don't do it, it is evil" sentence, and realise that the rest of the answer is probably not worth the time.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The uncivil behavior of people on this site sometimes makes me wonder why I even bother.

Comment: @wogsland I'm sorry that neither answer to your question was very understanding. :( But the short answer is: none of us can really help you, only the UX mods (who suspended you and sent that email) can tell you the specific reason why.  I hope you get it sorted out!

Comment: @Riker 1. I've read it somewhere in the SE, it is not disclosed information. 2. I mentioned around 3 different cage cases, only 1 is from me, it is expired long ago and it is absolutely not in a focal point. 3. Right, I inserted a literal answer to the literal problem.

Comment: @yannis Thank you very much, I consider this as an important argument to *not* remove this sentence.

Comment: @wogsland You're calling people *evil* in an answer, and then assert that people who inform you that that may have contributed to why some people choose to downvote it as "uncivl".  I don't think you know what "uncivil" actually means...

Comment: @peterh it's bolded and in written in a very rude way. You give no indication that it was long ago, it really sounds like you're complaining about your suspension.

Comment: You are welcome @peterh.

Comment: @peterh and what's the literal problem? I don't see that.  His question is "How can I learn the specific reason for a suspension?". You flat-out don't answer that.

Comment: @wogsland The solution is not to leave the site or to become silent on the metas, as you can see there is here a "collective punishment" by a hird of downvoters. This leads the sites into a false direction, the SE gets a false representation from the "community opinion" on them. You should fight it; you should communicate your opinion; you should help the community to get a real image from the opinions. Your upvote and accept would be enough to compensate 12 downvotes (although I will get probably more).

Comment: @Servy What are you talking about? Where did I call anyone evil? I haven't even answered any questions on UX StackExchange.

Comment: @Riker Thank you very much your diligence to comment the post, may I suggest the same diligence to understand it? And maybe a little bit lesser diligence to show your conditionless loyalty to the "community", it would be really nice.

Comment: @wogsland  He pinged the wrong person, meant to ping the answerer.

Comment: @Riker Then you totally misunderstood it. I tried to help a new user to understand, how things are going here and how to work around them. It is absolutely not from my suspension.

Comment: Note that "working around" a suspension ... may not be the best advise ...

Comment: @Bart Working around the problem. Yes, it is the best I have *to work around the problem of the unexplained suspensions*.

Comment: @Bart I think it was a dishonesting misinterpretation.

Comment: Given that you state *"It is long, in the case of such long bans it is better to open a new account."*, I don't see how any interpretation is dishonest. Working around a suspension in such a way will only lead to trouble. The user is suspended for a reason. Ignoring it and making new accounts is not the advise you should hand out.

Comment: @peterh So then how would you interpret your suggestion that people violate the rules to subvert their deserved suspension.

Comment: @Bart Would you like to read with the previous sentence together, trying to revive a little bit of sense of humor? I know, it is a very big task for many old SE users, but maybe you would be an exception.

Comment: If it was an attempt at humour, it's poorly executed and probably dangerous to those who happen upon it and think they should take your advice. Luckily the community has indicated what it thinks about your answer. Add to that that time and again you show a persistent lack of understanding about how the site works (or in the worst case you display a willful ignorance), so I think I can be forgiven for not seeing the humour in your statement.

Comment: @Bart The community indicated some quite different. The "community" (= hird of my fans simply hating my style and personality) indicated how they hate me. It hadn't anything to do with this sentence, without it my post had got around the same downs. But also you know this very well, it doesn't worth even a little bit to talk more about this. I changed the sentence, now we can see as the community revokes his downvotes, as the result of the improvement ;-)

Comment: Life is so much easier if you can swipe any criticism under the rug with a statement like "my fans simply hating my style and personality".

Comment: @peterh An aside: For future reference, an opening sentence like *"Mods can describe the reason, and in my opinion they should. If they don't do it, it is \*evil\*."* sets the tone of the remainder of the post. A quick downvote would not be unexpected. Presentation is as important as the point itself, tact can help win minds, or at least keep a reader engaged. I mean this to be constructive criticism (in an attempt to provide hopefully helpful advice) of your post here to address your quick downvote comment, I do not mean this to be any sort of commentary/opinion on the content itself.

Comment: (A good tactic in general is to reel in readers by starting off relating to the position that you expect the majority to have, and then transition smoothly into your counterpoint with a good case and a strong argument. This will generally lead to better, or at least more thoughtful, reception.)

Comment: @JasonC Ok, I agree your arguments. I changed this sentence.

Comment: @JasonC Thank you very much, it is a nice idea! I can follow this. My style is a counterpoint to a continuous declaration of loyalty to the system, what I find more annoying as if somebody, sometimes, is a little bit... too impressively emotional :-) I don't think that the SE would want our loyalty declaration from us, anyways we are already loyal by the fact that we are here. I think it wants our content what we produce. Thus, if somebody criticizes some aspect of the system (here: the badly reasoned suspensions), it shouldn't be treated as a personal insult, as many high-rep SE addicts do.

Comment: @Bart I think JasonC gave constructive critics and useful tips. If next time also you will have some, also you will find open doors.

Comment: Sure, next time I'll happily inform you that advising others to circumvent suspensions is a bad idea. I should have thought of that before. My apologies.

Comment: @Bart Yes, you had to be more constructive, but it was still much better as a silent downvote (+ also some to my some other posts). So I could learn, what is really the problem. I think the community doesn't focus really to the focal points of the posts, instead they find some non-focal triviality and if they've found them, they have already the reason to vote down. [Good read](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Graham%27s_Hierarchy_of_Disagreement.svg). I admit, for me, too.