# Do successive suspension times always increase?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, account-suspension

As far as I can tell, when a user is suspended multiple times, the length of the suspension increases each time.

My question is: Are suspension times *required* to increase, or do mods have the ability to, say, set arbitrary custom suspension lengths, so that a new suspension may be shorter than a previous one?

If so, is there a general set of guidelines that exists regarding suspension times and when to increase / decrease them based on the type of offense?

Comment: Unlikely but possible IMHO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks. The question is, to understand, roughly which factors and how strongly can result it.

Comment: C'mon Mod's are humans, and so is a group of them.

Comment: Feel free to rollback. If I understood the fundamental question correctly, it seems valid enough. If I didn't, apologies.

Comment: @JasonC It seems you have vastly changed the question. Why do you want to save it?

Comment: @DavidPostill Did I? If I misunderstood the question, just roll it back, no hard feelings. *shrug*

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ True, this is why I don't ask for exact rules, only for rough fist-rules. The goal is to get a better understand on the mods actions. As you know, many posts about the suspensions has a direct or indirect complaint about the unpredictability of the human decisions, this is why I find it useful to get a better understand about them.

Comment: Fist rules? Now I'm visualising mods as a bunch of brawlers guarding a nightclub.

Comment: Jeez, I hope I didn't overstep my bounds with that edit. I swear I was trying to help, but now I'm overrun with inexplicable feelings of guilt, lol. I think it's a decent question for somebody without experience with the mod tools to ask. This is why I usually just hide under the covers. Time to head back to the pillow fort.

Comment: @JasonC I think your edit helped more as harmed, this is why I didn't rollback it. I think this question will get a lot of downs, partially on its topic, partially on my general unpopularity, it doesn't matter how do you edit it. But I knew it from the first moment, and I accepted it.

Comment: @randal'thor Sad. Maybe read [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_thumb).

Comment: That's a rule of thumb, not a fist rule...

Comment: @ArtOfCode Yes, yes, but I think it doesn't mean so different things.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Oops. You wanted to say it means some really bad. Well, I am sorry. It was a mistake.

Answer (score 13):

**TL;DR:** Suspension lengths are up to moderators.

Is a shorter follow-up suspension *possible*? Sure. If there's a user who did something bad in their past, has gone a while without any more black marks on their record and has generally been awesome, and then steps out of line again briefly, a shorter suspension would be appropriate (i.e. disregarding previous suspension history). We don't hold grudges.

Is that kind of situation *likely*? In my experience, no. Users who get suspended almost always follow one of three paths:

1. Immediate rectification of the situation and learning from mistakes.
2. A brief period of appearing to follow the rules, then back to their old habits.
3. Retaliation against the evil moderators, and continuation of disregard for rules.

Users who go down path 1 won't get suspended again. On path 2, suspensions are either going to be a similar length or longer than the previous suspension, right up to the point where the user gets thumped with a 10-year network suspension. On path 3, you don't stand a chance of getting a shorter suspension - it'll just keep escalating.

So yeah, it's possible in theory, but unlikely in practice. Mostly, it depends on how much of a pain you are being/have been to the site.

Comment: "*almost* always" ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor Hey I never said a user couldn't follow 2 or 3 for a while, and then switch to 1 later on.

Answer (score 8):

**Yes, it's possible.** It has even happened in certain cases in the past.

But I don't like the idea of trying to impose a set of rules on when mods should escalate suspension lengths and when they should opt for a shorter period. Like many things moderation-related, **it's a judgement call**. That's why mods are mods - because they're trusted to make these judgement calls, to know their site's users well enough to judge whether So-and-so is a recurring troublemaker who needs a lengthy ban or someone who's basically improved but needs a small reminder. It all depends on the site, the person, the circumstances ... you can't really prepare for every possible scenario.

See also [my answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292940/278659) for more on the subjectivity of SE moderation.